# Bulk import one to many into DocumentDB collection

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb

I have two SQL Azure tables that I am combining into one collection via an import in DocumentDB.  Here is what the data looks like.  I've changed for brevity.

```
contact
- contact_id
- name
- ...

contact_attribute (max 10 records per user avg ~3)
- contact_attribute_id
- contact_id
- attribute_name
- attribute_value
- ...
```

I would like for the new JSON document to look like this:

```
{
    Id: "contact_id",
    name: "name",
    more: "...",
    attributes {
        "name": "value",
        "name2": "val2",
        "..." : "..."
    }
}
```

Is there is a way to write a SQL query that can run this through the DocumentDB Data Migration Tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tall and thin tables like your attributes table are notoriously tricky to manage with SQL. I don't think it's possible to do what you are asking with just SQL in the Data Migration Tool. I am not familiar with Azure Tables enough to have a strong opinion on which is best but two approaches come to mind:

1. Big batch. Download the entire Azure Table data set, alter it to the shape you want, and upload it in batches to DocumentDB.
2. One contact at a time. Query your parent table for one contact, then query the attributes table for all its attributes, then write the contact to DocumentDB. Repeat for all contacts.

Comment: Your suggestion brought on a hybrid approach of 1 and 2 for me to use.  It's unfortunate that I'll have to do it this way, but also makes sense.  Once I've built the logic for one set of tables, it should be easy to replicate.